# Объясните логику

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```js
let animal = {
  eats: true
};

function Rabbit(name) {
  Rabbit.prototype = animal
  this.name = name;

}

let rabbit1 = new Rabbit("White Rabbit");
let rabbit2 = new Rabbit("Black Rabbit");

console.log(rabbit1); // prototype = {constructor: Rabbit}
console.log(rabbit2); // prototype = {eats: true}
```

Почему у `rabbit1` prototype не изменился а у `rabbit2` изменился?

P.S  Да я знаю что надо писать `Rabbit.prototype = animal` вне функции, чтобы было ок. Просто хочу понять логику.

Comment: Ответ в самом вопросе мне кажется. Потому что ты говоришь кто у тебя родитель только лишь при вызове `Rabbit` а до этого он этого и знать не знал......пока функцию не вызвать строка кода в виде `Rabbit.prototype = animal` ещё не исполнена и никому ничего не назначена.

Comment: Потому что в выражении `new Rabbit` сперва создаётся результирующий объект, наследник `Rabbit.prototype`, и только затем вызывается функция `Rabbit`, с установленным `this` на только что созданный объект. На момент вызова конструктора, результирующий объект уже существует, и его прототип уже установлен. См. [оператор `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).